# Issue in Uploading Azure Blob : ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage, filestream

I am new to Azure. I am using the following part of the code to upload a file to Azure Blob.

```
public async Task<byte[]> UploadResultFile(string fileName, byte[] data)
        {

            if (StringUtilities.isBlankOrNull(fileName))
            {
                throw new EmptyStringException("File name cannot be empty or null");
            }
            // Creates a BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(config.StorageConnectionString);

            // Create the container and return a container client object
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(config.ResultContainer);

            // Create a local file in the ./data/ directory for uploading and downloading
            string localFilePath = Path.Combine(Experiment.DataFolder, fileName);

            // Write text to the file 
            // Adding a check to write a data in a file only if data is not equal to null
            // This is important as we need to re-use this method to upload a file in which data has already been written
            if (data != null)
            {
                File.WriteAllBytes(localFilePath, data);
            }

            // Get a reference to a blob
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);

            // Open the file and upload its data
            // FileStream uploadFileStream = File.OpenRead(localFilePath);
            using FileStream uploadFileStream = File.OpenRead(localFilePath);
            await blobClient.UploadAsync(uploadFileStream, true);
            uploadFileStream.Close();
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(blobClient.Uri.ToString());
        }
    }
```

But it is throwing an issue on uploadFileStream as following :

---

uploadFilestream.ReadOut threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOAperationException'

uploadFilestream.WriteOut threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOAperationException'

---

Subsequently, the console is throwing the following exception :

---

The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request

**Caught an exception: Retry failed after 6 tries. (The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.)
System.AggregateException: Retry failed after 6 tries. (The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.)
---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream.
---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (995): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.**

---

Any help in identifying and solving the issue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is your file size?

Comment: The file size is around 7 mb

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am uploading and it works for me.  Not saying your method won't work... can't confirm or deny unless I copy your code and create an app on my machine.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.RetryPolicies;

namespace My.Repositories
{
    public class BlobStorageRepository
    {
        private readonly CloudBlobContainer _cloudContainer;

        public BlobStorageRepository(string containerName, string connectionStringForStorageAccount)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
            
            storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionStringForStorageAccount);
            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            blobClient.DefaultRequestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions
            {
                // below timeout you can change to your needs
                MaximumExecutionTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                LocationMode = LocationMode.PrimaryThenSecondary
            };

            _cloudContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        }

        public int Save<T>(string blobName, byte[] contentBytes) where T : class
        {
            var bytes = contentBytes;
            var blockBlob = _cloudContainer.GetBlockBlobReference($"{blobName}.json");
            blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "application/json";
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                blockBlob.UploadFromStream(memoryStream);
            }
            return bytes.Length; // returning the number of bytes uploaded.
        }
    }
}
```